# Why can the 'as' operator not be used to parse non-nullable value types?

Tags: c#, theory

Every Developer has his/her own standards. Some developers like to `<type>.TryParse()`, some developers like to cast using `(type)object;`, and some developers love using the keywords instead.

I noticed a hiccup with the `'as'` operator - you cannot use it to perform conversions between non-nullable value types. I read the documentation on MSDN on the as Keyword and they also explain it as "You can use the as operator to perform certain types of conversions between compatible reference types or nullable types."

I tested this with the following:

```
                    int i = 0;
                    var k = i as int; //Breaks

                    int i = 0;
                    var k = i as int?; //Works
```

What were the reasons decided for the `as` keyword to perform in this way?

Comment: "Every Developer has his/her own standards. Some developers like to <type>.TryParse(), some developers like to cast using (type)object;, and some developers love using the keywords instead." This applies to developers outside a development team. When developing in a team, the first thing to agree upon is a common coding standard.

Comment: Not all developers work in a team though. I work solo from where I am now, and seems all the developers on this codebase had their own styles and standards (some of which burns my eyes :) )

Comment: The purpose of `as` is to convert to a particular type *if* the value is appropriate, and evaluate to a `null` value otherwise. Note the inclusion of `null` there. That description simply doesn't work for non-nullable types.

Comment: You don't use different forms because of a preference - you use different forms because they *do different things*. `as`, for example, will never invoke a conversion operator. `(type)object` may do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`as` operator would return `null` if parsing fails. Since `int` is a non nullable value type, you get the error, whereas `int?` or `Nullable<int>` can hold `null` value, that is why your second code snippet works.

See: [as (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> You can use the as operator to perform certain types of conversions
>   between compatible **reference types or nullable types**

also from the same [doc link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, **if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.**